# Distribution of zero-mean, independent, complex-valued, white noise terms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, statistics, stochastic-processes, wigner-transform

In [this](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.72.125335) paper (open access [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0504554)), in equations (13) and (14) they state that $W(\mathbf{x})$ is a zero-mean, independent, complex-valued, white noise term such that

$$\overline{W(\mathbf{x})W(\mathbf{x'})} = 0$$

$$\overline{W(\mathbf{x})W^*(\mathbf{x'})} = 2 \text{d}t \delta_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}'}$$

What does this mean? What is the distribution from which $W$ is sampled? Basically they have some (time) differential equations that they solve numerically, and $W(\mathbf{x})$ is some noise term they add to each pixel located at $\mathbf{x}$ at each time step. I want to know explicitly how they implemented this.

Comment: Without having read the papers (which it's often better to include the author(s) and title in case of link rot), I would assume that $W(x)$ is the [*Wiener process*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) & you'd just use normal distribution (mean zero, variance 1) for it.

Comment: Thank you. I think you might be right. I'm still unsure how to generalise the Weiner process to complex numbers though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Best guess would be $W_t=X_t+iY_t$ with $X_t,\,Y_t$ being independent, real-valued Wiener processes.

Comment: Actually, funnily enough, I checked the Wikipedia link after posting that comment & it mentions that expression towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

$W(x)$ is a complex-valued [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process):
$$
W(x)=X(x)+iY(x)
$$
where $X,\,Y$ are real-valued, independent Wiener processes.

The authors are asserting two conditions:

1. The product of two Wiener processes is zero
2. The product of a Wiener process and its complex conjugate is of order ${\rm d}t$

It seems to me that (1) states the independence of processes in each cell while (2) is the typical stochastic calculus condition of ${\rm d}W^2={\rm d}t$.<sup>1</sup>

While it's not something I normally do, I suspect that this would be numerically modeled via something like,

```
for each cell in grid:
    X = draw_from_normal(mean=0, variance=1)
    Y = draw_from_normal(mean=0, variance=1)
    W = complex(X, Y)
    ... continue with code ...
```

but probably extending to 3D positions.

<sup>1. This is simply stated in [the Wikipedia entry on Itô's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4's_lemma) with the marker *further explanation needed*; most stochastic calculus books should cover this more fully.</sup>

Comment: I'm curious as to what people who downvoted this would suggest is wrong with it.